# sh file can't work well but commands in sh can

Tags: linux, macos, shell

I'm using a bash shell to export some path,like this:

env.sh:

```
 export GOPATH=$GOPATH:$QBOXROOT/pili-zeus
 export PATH=$PATH:$QBOXROOT/pili-zeus/bin
```

after call `sh env.sh`,I call `echo $GOPATH` ,but nothing output,and I call `export` again to check the variables exported,but GOPATH isn't included.But when I copy these commands in the shell file,and execute them directly in command line,it can work!why this happens?I'm using mac.

Comment: when you call a command, you create a new subshell than inherits the environment, that means you change the `$PATH` of the subshell, instead of the login shell. Setting the `$PATH` is usually something you'd do in your `bashrc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `source env.sh` to get these variables stick to your context (i.e. terminal).

"source is a Unix command that evaluates the file following the command, as a list of commands, executed in the current context."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command)